# Radiant heat in ceiling

Tags: radiant-heating

How do I tell where the radiant wiring or pads, or whatever, is in my ceiling?  I want to install overhead cupboards but am afraid of ruining the heating.

Comment: You have radiant heat in your ceiling, or radiant heat in the floor above?

Comment: Ya, tester, never seen heat in the ceiling unless for the second floor.

Comment: I once lived in an apartment that had radiant electric heat in the ceiling; that was in the late 1970s, no idea how old the building was at that time.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a thing. Here in PA I've heard of several houses that are single story and have radiant heat in the ceiling. :(.

Comment: Here in the Pacific Northwest during the era of cheap hydro, a large portion of 1 story housing was equipped with radiant ceiling heat. The cables came in predetermined length kits with thermostat and were gridded on the gypsum board ceiling on nails with heads driven to within 1/8" of the surface and then covered with a sort of hard-set joint compound (not really a plaster job). In this era, you turn them to just come on (50F) and then run the heating stove to keep the thermostat off.

Answer (score 2):

You could order a cheap thermal camera ($200 from http://www.thermal.com/ ) and see them. I have no affiliation with that company but own one of their products and LOVE it.

Answer (score 0):

In the good old days, you could get magnetic pickup devices for recording incoming phone conversations. Combined with a small test amplifier or one of those portable tape recorders that had audio playback on record, you could swing the pickup across walls to find electrical cables and across the ceiling to find the ceiling heat cables.

Tends to be a bit better than those stud finders at finding the wires, you can hear the 60Hz hum quite loudly especially if it's carrying load when you're dead on top of the cable.